# Fullscreen video in Chrome shows URL in corner

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube, google-chrome-canary

When playing a fullscreen video in Chrome, the URL shows in the lower left corner. This happens for YouTube as well as other video players, where sometimes it covers the progress bar.

[image: YouTube fullscreen URL]

The suggestion to pause/wait on [this Yahoo Answers question](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140325152554AAHKwZY) doesn't really help. I usually use Chrome Canary but have experienced the same in regular Google Chrome from time to time as well. How can I get this to stop showing?

Answer (score 11):

According to [this Reddit response](http://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/22kl8v/help_hide_url_tip_at_bottom_of_fullscreen_videos/chw3jl4) by Booor, this happens when somehow you get two flash players enabled at the same time. To fix it, simply disable one of them:

1. Go to chrome://plugins
2. Click on "+ Details" on the right top corner
3. Find the flash player plugin and disable one of the DLLs

The DLL to be disabled should be the one that's not on the Chrome's folder, but I had the same problem, and disabling the external one didn't help, however, it worked when I disabled the internal one and enabled the external DLL.

I tried this fix and worked for me, and I noticed that the internal version that was problematic was version 13.0.0.214, while the external one that works is the 12.0.0.70. I don't know if this is relevant, but version 13.X may be the problem here.

Comment: Disabling one of the flash players helps on a lot of sites, but it can still happen on other sites. Here's the Chrome bug on this issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=380005#c76

Comment: It worked for me to disable the PepperFlash DLL ("Type: PPAPI (out-of-process)") which comes with the PortableApps version of Chrome.  Instead disabling the Macromedia DLL ("Type: NPAPI") did not work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, I also disable others flash plugin of Chrome but the issue still exist. 
I found a solution, you can **double click** to get full screen instead of click on full screen icon, the URL status will not show.

Answer (score 1):

Hey brother here's what you do, I had the same problem today so i was really mad looking for answers but I figured it out right click on the video then settings. Under display remove the tick "Enable hardware acceleration" and refresh page. The End

Comment: I've tried disabling hardware acceleration but no joy. It's still showing the URL in the corner.